# Select option not showing data after selected option

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to get a list of the "states" after I select the "country".

The list of countries appear correctly, but when I select the country the states don't actually show up in dropdown selection form.

I'm using ajax to send the data to ajaxData.php from index.php, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is index.php

```
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country').on('change',function(){
        var countryID = $(this).val();
        if(countryID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'marka_id='+countryID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#state').html(html);
                    $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
            $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
        }
    });

    $('#state').on('change',function(){
        var stateID = $(this).val();
        if(stateID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'modeli_id='+stateID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#state').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
           ''); 
        }
    });
});
</script>

<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

//Get all country data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM marka WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY marka_name ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="">SelectMarken </option>
    <?php
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['marka_id'].'">'.$row['marka_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Country doesnt exist</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
<select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="">Select state</option>
</select>
```

and this is : ajaxData.php

```
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

if(isset($_POST["marka_id"]) && !empty($_POST["marka_id"])){
    //Get all state data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM modeli WHERE `marka_id` = ".$_POST['marka_id']." AND `status` = 1 ORDER BY modeli_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select modelin</option>';
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['modeli_id'].'">'.$row['modeli_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Modeli doesnt exist</option>';
    }
}


?>
```

[UPDATED CODE] *I forgot to post it immediately, so now this is what I have and it works.*

ajaxData.php

```
<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

if(isset($_POST["marka_id"]) && !empty($_POST["marka_id"])){
    //Get all state data
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM modeli WHERE `marka_id` = ".$_POST['marka_id']." AND `status` = 1 ORDER BY modeli_name ASC");

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;

    //Display states list
    if($rowCount > 0){
      $optionHTML = '<option value="">Select modelin</option>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $optionHTML .= '<option value="'.$row['modeli_id'].'">'.$row['modeli_name'].'</option>';
    }

echo $optionHTML;
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Modeli doesnt exist</option>';
    }
}


?>
```

index.php

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#country').on('change',function(){
        var countryID = $(this).val();
        if(countryID){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'marka_id='+countryID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#state').html(html);
                    $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');

        }
    });

});
</script>

<?php
//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

//Get all country data
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM marka WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY marka_name ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;
?>
<select name="country" id="country">
    <option value="">SelectMarken </option>
    <?php
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<option value="'.$row['marka_id'].'">'.$row['marka_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Ss</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
<select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="">Select state</option>
</select>
```

Comment: [Exploits of a Mom](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom)

Comment: marka_id is posted for country change, modeli_id is for state, so I think thats correct

Comment: Do `alert(html);` inside the `success` callback function and see what you're getting back from the server.

Comment: yes it is correct

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console? Check the Network tab to see if the AJAX request is being sent and received correctly, and examine the response.

Comment: @Barmar There is not a single error in console!

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was at the #state function, I had another part of code which was waiting data for cities once the state was selected.

So I had to make 'else' turn nothing for it to work.

Thanks guys.

Comment: @barmar Just edited and posted updated code. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: The solution should be in the answer, not the question. You don't have to post the whole thing, just the part with the fix.